# Making \cventry fields all raggedright instead of justified in moderncv

Tags: horizontal-alignment, moderncv

I'm looking to use `moderncv` for a resume. Using `\cventry` (well, using any of the moderncv environments, really) makes all the text justified, but I'd like it to be ragged-right throughout the whole document. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

\firstname{Some}
\familyname{Dude}
\title{CV}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Using cventry:}
\cventry{year--year}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, AS YOU CAN PLAINLY SEE}{THIS IS ALSO JUSTIFIED}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, TOO}{AND THIS IS JUSTIFIED AS WELL}{I would like all this stuff to be raggedright, however. The "year-year" is not important. }

\end{document}
```

I have tried editing moderncv.cls and moderncvstyleclassic.sty and have found no way to just change "justified" to "raggedright".

As far as I understand, `\cventry` uses a `tabular` environment which gets an array of `p` passed to it for the alignment of the columns. Changing that `p` to `r` freaks out the compiler.

There is the option of using cvline and passing it a `\raggedright` in the second argument (and doing all the formatting manually), but that seems like a brute-force solution I'd prefer to avoid.

Pretty clueless what to do, appreciate your help!

Edit following David's and Werner's solutions:

Here's an MWE with more content without the solutions.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

\firstname{Some}
\familyname{Dude}
\title{CV}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Using cventry:}

\cventry{year--year}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, AS YOU CAN PLAINLY SEE}{THIS IS ALSO JUSTIFIED}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, TOO}{AND THIS IS JUSTIFIED AS WELL}{I would like all this stuff to be raggedright, however. The "year-year" is not important. }

\cventry{year--year}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, AS YOU CAN PLAINLY SEE}{THIS IS ALSO JUSTIFIED}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, TOO}{AND THIS IS JUSTIFIED AS WELL}{I would like all this stuff to be raggedright, however. The "year-year" is not important. }

\cventry{year--year}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, AS YOU CAN PLAINLY SEE}{THIS IS ALSO JUSTIFIED}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, TOO}{AND THIS IS JUSTIFIED AS WELL}{I would like all this stuff to be raggedright, however. The "year-year" is not important. }

\section{Using cventry:}

\cventry{year--year}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, AS YOU CAN PLAINLY SEE}{THIS IS ALSO JUSTIFIED}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, TOO}{AND THIS IS JUSTIFIED AS WELL}{I would like all this stuff to be raggedright, however. The "year-year" is not important. }

\cventry{year--year}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, AS YOU CAN PLAINLY SEE}{THIS IS ALSO JUSTIFIED}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, TOO}{AND THIS IS JUSTIFIED AS WELL}{I would like all this stuff to be raggedright, however. The "year-year" is not important. }

\cventry{year--year}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, AS YOU CAN PLAINLY SEE}{THIS IS ALSO JUSTIFIED}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, TOO}{AND THIS IS JUSTIFIED AS WELL}{I would like all this stuff to be raggedright, however. The "year-year" is not important. }



\end{document}
```

Here's a screenshot of the pdf produced by the solutions; sorry for the quality, stitched it quickly together.

[image: As you can see, Werner's solution seems to add some space between the <code>\cventry</code>s (in comparison to the MWE with the standard justification, while David's doesn't. Not sure why.]

As you can see, Werner's solution seems to add some space between the `\cventry`s (in comparison to the MWE with the standard justification, while David's doesn't. Not sure why. If both are used simultaneously, the spaces stay.

So I'm upvoting both solutions, but considering David's as the right answer. Thanks a lot for the quick help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin them with a greeting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{\raggedright%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut\endgraf%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small\raggedright #7\end{minipage}}\fi}}

\firstname{Some}
\familyname{Dude}
\title{CV}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Using cventry:}
\cventry{year--year}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, AS YOU CAN PLAINLY SEE}{THIS IS ALSO JUSTIFIED}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, TOO}{AND THIS IS JUSTIFIED AS WELL}{I would like all this stuff to be raggedright, however. The "year-year" is not important. }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you both for your quick answers! Have checked both solutions with more CV content, David's solution seems to work better - editing post for screenshots.

Comment: That with `#7` does not seem to work in my case? The `\small` information below is still justified, isn't it? Moreover: what about the `\cvitem`-fields? (I know that wasn't part of the original question.)

Comment: @ClintEastwood small code in #7 looks raggedright to me looking at the code here and the image?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : Ok right. I was mislead by the OP's images of your and Werner's suggestion *and* by the fact that I removed `\endgraf` from your solution, because I wanted to avoid the extra space your solution adds. But, as it seems, `¨raggedright` does not work without an an ending paragraph, does it?

Comment: @ClintEastwood I think I know what you mean (I also removed `endgraf`), this worked for me for the `cventry`: 

`\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{% 
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{\raggedright%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small\raggedright #7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
`

Comment: and this for `cvitem`: `\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedright\hintstyle{#2} &\raggedright{#3}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}`

Answer (score 7):

The following is similar to [David's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210356/5764), with a patch provided by [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch):

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
% \xpatchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\xpatchcmd{\cvitem}{#3}{\raggedright #3\par}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{\small}{\small\raggedright}{}{}
```

Place the above content *after* specifying the `\moderncvtheme` as `classic`. The reason for this is because `\cvitem` and `\cventry` are defined within the specific theme.

Comment: Thank you both for your quick answers! Have checked both solutions with more CV content, David's solution seems to work better - editing post for screenshots.